# Simple proxy class dependency injection in C# dotnet core 2.0 using StructureMap.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, proxy, .net-core, structuremap

I am using dotnet core 2.0 and [StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) for IoC and dependency injection. I am trying to creat a proxy class for validation. I am trying to imply to IoC's DI to use `ComponentDataAccessorProxy` whenever `IComponentDataAccessor` is used and also satisfy `ComponentDataAccessorProxy` dependency which is `ComponentDataAccessor` and satisfy it's dependency which is `IMongoDatabase` without getting into circular dependency exception. I am wondering if it is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is interface:

```
public interface IComponentDataAccessor
{
    Component SaveComponent(Component componentToAdd);
}
```

This is concrete definition or concrete type:

```
public class ComponentDataAccessor : IComponentDataAccessor
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    public ComponentDataAccessor(IMongoDatabase database)
    {
      _database = database;
    }

    public Component SaveComponent(Component componentToAdd)
    {
        // actually save the componentToAdd
    }
}
```

And lastly this is a proxy class:

```
public class ComponentDataAccessorProxy : IComponentDataAccessor
{
    private readonly IComponentDataAccessor _componentDataAccessor;

    public ComponentDataAccessorProxy(IComponentDataAccessor componentDataAccessor)
    {
        _componentDataAccessor = componentDataAccessor;
    }

    public Component SaveComponent(Component componentToAdd)
    {
        // do some validation here, if everything is good then call 
        // concrete class otherwise throw an exception

        return _componentDataAccessor.SaveComponent(componentToAdd);
    }
}
```

Failed attempts:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Configure(config =>
{
    // failed attempt #1
    config.Forward<IComponentDataAccessor, ComponentDataAccessorProxy>();

    // failed attempt #2
    config.For<IComponentDataAccessor>().Use<ComponentDataAccessorProxy>();
});
```

Comment: StructureMap documentation http://structuremap.github.io/quickstart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://structuremap.github.io/interception-and-decorators/), you should be using something like this:

```
config.For<IComponentDataAccessor>().DecorateAllWith<ComponentDataAccessorProxy>();
config.For<IComponentDataAccessor>().Use<ComponentDataAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
container.Configure(
    config =>
    {
        config.For<IComponentDataAccessor>().Use<ComponentDataAccessor>()
            .Name = "innerComponentDataAccessor";
        config.For<IComponentDataAccessor>().Use<ComponentDataAccessorProxy>()
            .Ctor<IComponentDataAccessor>()
            .Is(c=>c.GetInstance<IComponentDataAccessor>("innerComponentDataAccessor"));
    });
```

There's one registration that says, for `IComponentDataAccessor` use `ComponentDataAccessor`, and that registration is given a name, "innerComponentDataAccessor".

Then the "real" registration for `IComponentDataAccessor` uses `ComponentDataAccessorProxy`. When that class's constructor requires an argument of type `IComponentDataAccessor`, the container will resolve the named registration from the previous step.